# Windows Boot gone after installing Fedora 26

Tags: boot, windows

I have two separate SSDs in my PC, one with Windows 10 and one that had Ubuntu 16.04. I uninstalled Ubuntu 16.04 from the second SSD and installed Fedora 26 on that drive. Since installing Fedora, I am unable to boot into Windows. I have tried everything I can think of, but even the grub2-mkconfig won't detect my Windows installation on sdb. Here's an output of the fdisk -l command:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0F28711F-75EE-4815-B915-D23B0680B869

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    411647    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sda2   411648   2508799   2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2508800 488396799 485888000 231.7G Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B0F5AD39-E953-4CDA-9738-99F0C1928757

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048 467937279 467935232 223.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb2  467937280 468858879    921600   450M Windows recovery 
environment
```

I have tried creating a bootable Windows 10 USB using the ISO file provided by Microsoft to do a repair (I created is using the Gnome Disks app to resotre the ISO file to the USB), but when I try to boot from it I always get a screen that says: "Reboot and select proper Boot Device. Press any key to continue."

I can access the Windows 10 SSD from Fedora and see all the files, but I can't boot into Windows. Any suggestions? I'm about three drinks into this so sorry if I didn't provide enough info. :) - This is a garbage situation.

UPDATE: I formatted the entire Ubuntu installation on the second SSD using the Fedora installer. Grub entries only reflect Fedora. Every other question seems to point to adding Windows in the grub 40_custom.confg file, but every example I've seen fails to boot. I know I can't be the only one running into this. I don't understand how if Ubuntu was installed on a separate hard drive, how formatting that drive and installing Fedora would have removed the ability to boo to the Windows SSD. I did not change anything in the UEFI/EFI menu.

UPDATE 2: The Windows system is installed on /dev/sdb. All of the files are intact and I can mount the drive from within Fedora. I am trying to figure out how to properly link up the Grub2 bootloader menu entry to the bootmgr on the Windows hard drive (/dev/sdb). It's frustrating, because nothing - literally nothing - has changed on the Windows SSD, but I cannot boot from the drive in BIOS. When I try without the Windows live ISO USB plugged in, I get a black screen with: "Reboot and select proper Boot Device. Press any key to continue."

Every example of adding a menu entry i.e.:

```
menuentry "Windows 10" {
    insmod ntfs
    set root=(hd1,1)
    drivemap -s (hd1) ($root)
    #ntldr /bootmgr
    or chainloader +1
}
```

Results in a command not found error such drivemap, ntldr etc.

UPDATE: I just reinstalled Windows and everything works fine now. I have no idea how the Window boot manager could have been overwritten by the Ubuntu Grub bootloader since it is on a separate drive, but I am no expert in Grub or boot records by any stretch.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a Windows support issue.

Comment: Did you change something in your efi-menu before you install Feodora?

Comment: What you call the "second SSD" is apparently `/dev/sda`. That's quite misleading, you should rephrase. Besides, what does your EFI partition contain? (probably `/boot/efi`)

Comment: Please read [this on how to join your accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)